# sort data in mySQL

Tags: python, mysql

my table is

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| Name      | Weight | Height |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| Amin      |     75 |    180 |
| Mahdi     |     90 |    190 |
| Moahammad |     75 |    175 |
| Ahmad     |     60 |    175 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

I want sort a table from bigger Height and if Height is equal print 
lower weight first.
and the result like this

```
Mahdi 190 90
Amin 180 75
Ahmad 175 60
Mohammad 175 75
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY Height DESC, Weight;`

Comment: `ORDER BY Height DESC, Weight ASC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use height as descending order then weight in ascending order

```
select name, hieght, weight
from tablename
order by height desc, weight
```

Comment: this is the correct answer and work for me tanx a lot

Comment: if it helped you please mark it as answer @fariborznajafi